# How to use idiom "taken aback"

Tags: idioms

Is this sentence correct:

> I was taken aback on seeing my result card

Is it right? If not, then how should I put this idiom in such kind of sentence?

Comment: Your example is a perfect use of this expression in its usual sense of _surprised and confused._

Comment: I would slightly favor the preposition *at* instead of *on*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly correct (although in the U.S. we usually refer to it as a *report* card and not a *result* card).

Some other examples:

> I was taken aback to learn who they were going to vote for in the election.
>
> They were taken aback to see Michael wearing white after Labor Day.
>
> Michael was taken aback on hearing that they're going to reboot the "Spiderman" movies yet again.

Comment: Is _by_ also a common usage before gerund? I mean does _I was taken aback **by** seeing my report card_ sound off?

Comment: I would just say "I was taken aback by my report card".  Otherwise "on" sounds better with the gerund.  "I was taken aback *on* seeing my report card," "I was taken aback on finding out the bad news," etc.

Comment: You could reorganize the sentence as well and it would be just as impactful while retaining the idiom. For example, "Upon seeing my result card, I was taken aback." Granted, it makes the original statement a bit more dramatic.